# "gdown : The term 'gdown' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program..."

Tags: python, pip, path

I'm getting the error when trying to run gdown.

> gdown : The term 'gdown' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
> included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1hs9HM0XJ2LPFghcn7ZMOs5qu5HexPXw ...
> + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gdown:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I've been stuck at this for the past hour. I'm trying to run this on my Windows machine, including various terminals like Powershell/cmd prompt/ISE, Git Bash, and VSCode terminal. I also added my ...../Python/Python12/Scripts to the PATH/environment variables.

I also verified that gdown is installed:

> Name: gdown
> Version: 4.7.1
> Summary: Google Drive direct download of big files.
> Home-page: http://github.com/wkentaro/gdown
> Author: Kentaro Wada
> Author-email: www.kentaro.wada@gmail.com
> License: MIT
> Location: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages
> Requires: beautifulsoup4, filelock, requests, six, tqdm
> Required-by:

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're running ```gdown``` in a powershell?  Where is ```gdown``` installed?  Did you add that to the path?

Comment: @ewokx Yup I did. I tried running in powershell and git bash. Same error